# Scraping a list of urls from a csv with Beautiful soup

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

I have a list of urls in urls.csv

```
http://www.indianngos.org/ngo_detail.aspx?nprof=292241149
http://www.indianngos.org/ngo_detail.aspx?nprof=9986241242
http://www.indianngos.org/ngo_detail.aspx?nprof=319824125
```

and my code goes as below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

with open('urls.csv' , 'r') as csv_file:
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

for line in csv_reader:
    r = requests.get(line[0]).text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r,'lxml')

    csv_file = open('output.csv', 'w')

    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(['Ngoname', 'CEO', 'City', 'Address', 'Phone', 'Mobile', 'E-mail'])
    # print(soup.prettify())

    ngoname = soup.find('h1')
    print('NGO Name :', ngoname.text)

    ceo = soup.find('h2', class_='').text
    ceo_name = ceo.split(':')
    print('CeoName:', ceo_name[1])

    city = soup.find_all('span')
    print('City :', city[5].text)

    address = soup.find_all('span')
    print('Address :', address[6].text)

    phone = soup.find_all('span')
    print('Phone :', phone[7].text)

    mobile = soup.find_all('span')
    print('Mobile :', mobile[8].text)

    email = soup.find_all('span')
    print('Email_id :', email[9].text)

 csv_writer.writerow([ngoname.text, ceo_name[1], city[5].text, address[6].text, phone[7].text, mobile[8].text, email[9].text])

csv_file.close()
```

I am only getting the last url's data from this scraper.
how do i get data from each url one below the other in the output csv

Comment: Did you already try debugging your code?

Comment: Why are you reading the urls using a `csv.reader`? Why not just `with open('urls.txt') as f: for url in f: # ...`? Iterating over a file gives you the lines.

Comment: I tried but didn't get it right.

Comment: Can you @BaileyParker give me an example code.

Comment: No. You can read the docs and try writing it yourself. What I gave you is quite literally copy and pastable into your current code. But, we are not here to do all the work for you. Now, if while trying to fix it you run into another problem, by all means feel free to ask.

Comment: @BaileyParker thanks, i was just making sure that it would work for a csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep your output file open for all three of your CSV files. Currently you are overwriting each time:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

with open('urls.csv', newline='') as f_urls, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_urls = csv.reader(f_urls)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(['Ngoname', 'CEO', 'City', 'Address', 'Phone', 'Mobile', 'E-mail'])

    for line in csv_urls:
        r = requests.get(line[0]).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')

        ngoname = soup.find('h1')
        print('NGO Name :', ngoname.text)

        ceo = soup.find('h2', class_='').text
        ceo_name = ceo.split(':')
        print('CeoName:', ceo_name[1])

        city = soup.find_all('span')
        print('City :', city[5].text)

        address = soup.find_all('span')
        print('Address :', address[6].text)

        phone = soup.find_all('span')
        print('Phone :', phone[7].text)

        mobile = soup.find_all('span')
        print('Mobile :', mobile[8].text)

        email = soup.find_all('span')
        print('Email_id :', email[9].text)

        csv_output.writerow([ngoname.text, ceo_name[1], city[5].text, address[6].text, phone[7].text, mobile[8].text, email[9].text])
```

This approach would give you an output file containing:

```
Ngoname,CEO,City,Address,Phone,Mobile,E-mail
A CONSUMER WELFARE SOCIETY, Bhanu Pratap,Delhi,201 Vardhman Grand Market Sec 3 Dwarka New Delhi 110075,011-20078086,,admin@consumercourt.in
AADARSH MAHILA KALYAN SAMITI, Kusum Lata,Delhi,"G-61, Jai Vihar Extn. Baprola, Najafgarh, New Delhi-110043",011-28012307,9953574659,snehayadav96@yahoo.com
AAJ KI AWAJ JAN KALYAN SOCIETY, YASHPAL SINGH BALIYAN,Delhi,HEAD OFFICE,011-43029251,9899668750,aajkiawaj@gmail.com
```

Comment: thank you for teaching me the right way, i just started learning to code. thanks again.